# LaTeX Coding for Statement of Purpose

Tags: templates

I need a LaTeX sample for statement of purpose. 
I found a [sample statement of purpose file](https://bitbucket.org/soonhok/sop/src/83138ee16b8e36752a36c6430350867c98eeec52/main.tex?at=master) through Internet. It seems OK but not functioning on my Windows PC as it uses XeLaTeX files.

Now I am looking for [a little bit different file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zbmxjk98u6cbi6t/Statement%20of%20Purpose%20V-1.pdf). I created this using Microsoft Office. I don't know where I need to make changes to get the exactly similar look like the Microsoft Office one. Are there any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Using `xelatex` on Windows is not a problem, but the fonts specified needs to be installed. In this case you need Adobe Caslon Pro, Monaco and Optima Regular, or choose some different fonts (lines 35-38 in the template).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't need XeLaTeX, nor many of the customization in that template.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tgschola} % or any other font package you like

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{%
  \footnotesize\sffamily
  \yourname\quad
  web: \textcolor{blue}{\itshape\yourweb}\quad
  \textcolor{blue}{\youremail}}

\newcommand{\soptitle}{Statement of Purpose}
\newcommand{\yourname}{firstname lastname}
\newcommand{\youremail}{email@address.edu}
\newcommand{\yourweb}{https://www.abcd.com/}

\newcommand{\statement}[1]{\par\medskip
  \underline{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{#1:}}}\space
}

\usepackage[
  colorlinks,
  breaklinks,
  pdftitle={\yourname - \soptitle},
  pdfauthor={\yourname},
  unicode
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}\LARGE\soptitle\\
\large of \yourname\ (ECE PhD applicant for Fall---2014)
\end{center}

\hrule
\vspace{1pt}
\hrule height 1pt

\bigskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam
sodales, ipsum a commodo tempus, arcu magna bibendum turpis, at
eleifend nulla lectus et turpis. Etiam nisi risus, ultricies at auctor
id, mollis vitae lorem. Morbi vel rhoncus mi. Aenean euismod eros
vitae turpis porttitor varius. Donec aliquam fringilla tellus nec
venenatis. Fusce ornare tempor metus, non bibendum massa vehicula sit
amet. Integer ultrices rutrum velit, in facilisis augue feugiat sed.
Fusce luctus tristique pretium. Nullam consequat tincidunt sem, at
gravida purus gravida at. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc ante leo, volutpat
pretium fringilla id, malesuada et dolor. Aliquam blandit, magna eget
porta tempus, quam neque ultrices mi, vel pretium ipsum ante tristique
massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et
malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.

\statement{Project \#1}
Morbi sed sapien ut ante elementum luctus vitae et libero. Praesent
felis enim, elementum nec suscipit non, suscipit a diam. Nulla
vulputate facilisis orci, vel iaculis odio feugiat id. Fusce in dolor
interdum ante dignissim bibendum. Nullam euismod interdum commodo.
Etiam a mauris ac purus dignissim ultrices at eu nisl. Suspendisse
varius ipsum eu massa ullamcorper in convallis nulla vulputate.

\statement{Project \#2}
Nulla non mauris quis mi pellentesque interdum. Sed venenatis pretium
sem sed pretium. Pellentesque et augue velit, ut bibendum leo. Proin
congue nisl id leo tristique sagittis. Curabitur id diam in turpis
faucibus pharetra eget elementum orci. Sed vel nunc nibh. Praesent non
enim eros, sed convallis dui. Pellentesque accumsan viverra dolor sed
luctus.

Sed non posuere leo. Curabitur eu est ut tellus ultrices ornare quis
ut tortor. Aliquam faucibus mauris in leo tincidunt euismod. Aliquam
lacinia euismod dolor, tempus gravida erat facilisis elementum.
Pellentesque pretium pharetra orci, eu consequat arcu dapibus et.
Quisque quis dolor magna. Fusce gravida risus at ipsum lobortis id
facilisis justo malesuada. Donec egestas placerat congue. Curabitur
eget diam at odio iaculis pellentesque quis in est. Aenean sit amet
sodales tortor. Morbi a nulla magna.

\statement{Conclusion}
Praesent vel mi pharetra justo lacinia consectetur. In in odio neque.
Donec in tellus nulla, quis fringilla quam. In hac habitasse platea
dictumst. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Maecenas nisi elit, dictum
at fringilla vitae, vestibulum vitae ligula. Vestibulum ante ipsum
primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis
placerat ipsum sit amet ante fermentum condimentum. Nunc facilisis
eros euismod nisl euismod id egestas turpis imperdiet. Etiam
consectetur risus vitae augue scelerisque in fringilla odio
vestibulum. Ut venenatis convallis suscipit. Maecenas cursus dignissim
semper. Vestibulum tempor lectus vel justo consequat vel faucibus enim
viverra. Donec nunc ligula, luctus nec molestie eget, aliquam vel
lectus.

\end{document}
```

[image]

For having a page number at the bottom and reducing the spacing between header and first line, here are some modifications.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  letterpaper,
  margin=1in,
  headsep=4pt, % separation between header rule and text
]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tgschola}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{%
  \footnotesize\sffamily
  \yourname\quad
  web: \textcolor{blue}{\itshape\yourweb}\quad
  \textcolor{blue}{\youremail}}
\fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\newcommand{\soptitle}{Statement of Purpose}

%%%% from here it's the same as before
```

Comment: Thank you for your support .. I have one more request 1) how to reduce the line spacing in the header section (referring the line of statement of purpose of first name last name )  2) how to put the page number in the bottom similar to the pdf (like page 1 of 1)

Comment: @ibrahimkbd I add only what needs to be changed; from the last line showed everything else is like before.

Comment: another things, a) how to control the after paragraph .. 2) after first name last name (phd applicant fall) a little big space .. Can we control that  part ? 3) The header font size is very small .. how to increase that little bit     Thanks once again

Comment: @ibrahimkbd For the header, change `\footnotesize` into `\small`; for a wider space after “lastname” use `\qquad` instead of `\quad`. I don't understand what you mean by “after paragraph”.

Comment: @egreg: Can you show me how to remove the header of the SOP (I mean the name, web, email, and the line at the top of the SOP)? Thank you so much!

Comment: Just comment the lines defining the macro `\fancyhead`.

Comment: So do I need to delete my question?

Comment: Thank you @projetmbc. I've commented out the macro but it only deletes the name, web, and email except for the top line. What should I do to remove the line and still keep the fancy format of page numbers? One more question and then I will remove this, please.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/241691)