# Latex template for statement of purpose

Tags: templates

I have used ModernCV template to write resumes, Beamer to prepare presentations. Likewise, is there any standard Latex template for writing Statement of Purpose (SOP) or Research Proposal?

Comment: Looking at an [image search](https://www.google.ch/search?q=statement+of+purpose&safe=on&tbm=isch) a SOP seems to be doable with a simple `scrartcl` (KOMA-Script) or `article` document class.

Comment: Agreeing with @Habi when looking at [Statement of Purpose Template](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5371) or [LaTeX Coding for Statement of Purpose](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150900) or [latex template or example for personal statement](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1966778)